# how to get local Contact account type?

Tags: android

I am trying to get local contact account type.Below is the code for it which works fine on Samsung devices but not working on sony, micromax etc.Please suggest where is the issue and to solve this

```
public void GetDefaultAccountNameAndType() {
String accountType = "";
String accountName = "";

long rawContactId = 0;
Uri rawContactUri = null;
ContentProviderResult[] results = null;

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null).build());

try {
    results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    ops.clear();
}

for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {
    rawContactUri = result.uri;
    rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
}

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
        , new String[] {RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME}
        , RawContacts._ID+"=?"
        , new String[] {String.valueOf(rawContactId)}
        , null);

if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    if(!c.isAfterLast()) {
        accountType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
        accountName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME));
    }
}

getContentResolver().delete(rawContactUri, null, null);

c.close();
c = null;

System.out.println(accountType);
System.out.println(accountName);

//preference.setString("contactAccountType", accountType);
//preference.setString("contactAccountName", accountName);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS, it works on sony but not in samsung. Don't know why is it so. I am also looking into the same issue.

```
/**
 * Get All Account available in Phone and add into list
 */
private void getAllAccounts() {
    int counter = 0;
    final AccountManager accManager = AccountManager
            .get(Activity.this);
    final Account accounts[] = accManager.getAccounts();

    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Name " + accounts[i].name + ", Type "
                    + accounts[i].type);
    }
}
```